# Representation and efficiency of Switch statements in bytecode?

Tags: java, performance, switch-statement, bytecode, representation

Though a switch statement can be represented as a series of if statements, it appears that when a Java switch statement is compiled into bytecode, a different approach is used.

- What is the representation used by bytecode?
- I assume this alternate representation is for efficiency reasons, so how does the efficiency compare to that of just an if statement representation?
- Are there any other considerations that have led to using this representation?

Comment: This [link](http://www.artima.com/underthehood/flowP.html) covers it well.

Answer (score 5):

Read the [spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Instructions2.doc14.html#tableswitch) .  In Java, if you code a switch statement, then depending on various things the switch is converted into a tableswitch instruction in bytecode.  Essentially a jump table.  What the bytecode looks like may be irrelavent though, if the JIT can optimize it into something more efficient.  This is of course, platform dependent.

Comment: Part of what I am trying to understand is what makes this tableswith (jump table) any more efficient than the bytecode if-statements that also jump to a particular point.

Comment: Then you're not asking a Java specific performance question - this is something you can easily google 'jump table vs if'.  Here's something to get you started: http://www.dotnetperls.com/if-switch-performance

Comment: That is an interesting link, but I am specifically interested in the JVM.

Answer (score -1):

Consider this simple JavaScript example

```
var SwitchCases = [
// case 1
 function() { return "one"; },
// case 2
 function() { return "two"; },
// case 3
 function() { return "three"; },
// default
 function() { return ""; }
];
var SwitchCaseMin = 1;
var SwitchCaseMax = 3;
var SwitchCaseDefault = true;

function FakeSwitchCase(switch) {
 if(switch > SwitchCaseMax || switch < SwitchCaseMin) {
  if(SwitchCaseDefault == true) {
   return SwitchCases[SwitchCases.length-1]();
  }
 } else {
  return SwitchCases[switch - SwitchCaseMin]();
 }
}
```

The key part is

```
SwitchCases[switch - SwitchCaseMin]();
```

Imagine if there were many cases the code that evaluates them wouldn't grow any larger, but if we used IF..ELSE IF...ELSE the execution time would grow with each added case.

In a real switch case implementation SwitchCases (from the above code) would be an array/look-up-table of Labels (read: offsets) to the locations in the function where the Case code blocks appeared.

*EDIT*

In java the above switch case would be compiled to the following byte code

```
[tableswitch 0xAA]
[padding bytes 0x00 or 0x0000 or 0x000000]
[offset of SwitchCases[3]] // default case
[SwitchCaseMin] // 1
[SwitchCaseMax] // 3
[offset of SwitchCases[0]] // case 1
[offset of SwitchCases[1]] // case 2
[offset of SwitchCases[2]] // case 3
```

Comment: My question is regarding `Java` and the corresponding `bytecode`, so I don't think that a `Javascript` example is all that appropriate.

Comment: @Treebranch - I was a bit ambiguous but the above code coincides with how the Java byte code works, I'll make an update to elaborate.