# Why does it used R.id.buttonX in onClick method instead of comparing view to exists buttons?

Tags: android

I have onClick method, for example, in Activity. Why it is a bad aproach to handle such way?

```
@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
    if (v == mBtnGo || v == mBtnBack) {
        handleActionClick();
    } else if (v == mBtnNext) {
        handleNextClick();
    }
}
```

Supposed to use this logic:

```
@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_go:
        case R.id.btn_back:
            handleActionClick();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_next:
            handleNextClick();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Switch-case is much faster than if-else.

Comment: false. There is no performance difference between switch and if. edit: I'm probably wrong and you are right, Bruno: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8748981/507339 . That said in this case where you only have two cases, the difference is negligable

Answer (score 1):

Both of the methods will work.

When dealing with multiple clicks inside a single `onClick(`) method
the second method allows you to use a switch statement,

which is faster and far more readable than a chain of if-else statements.

Answer (score 1):

Sometime we don't need keeping a reference of a View. We just want to register for click event like: `findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener()`

And I also prefer using switch instead of if-else